# Syntax error in SQL query for MS Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I am making the form to insert the records in table. I am unable to run this query as it is showing me the syntax error. I tried lot but not able to find the error. My query is as follow.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "
  INSERT into Database2Sample(
      nyu_id, location1, location2, 
      first_name, middle_name, last_name, 
      full_name, instructor_sis_id, instructor_email, 
      intstructor_net_id, personal_email, CV_link, 
      employee_nyu_global_site, highest_degree, degree_subject_area, 
      degree_status, degree_granting_institution, accomplishments, 
      Other_employee, WSQ_home_campus, teaching_language_course) 
  VALUES 
    ('" & Me.nyu_id & "', '" 
        & Me.location1 & "', '" 
        & Me.location2 & "', '"
        & Me.first_name & "', '" 
        & Me.middle_name & "', '" 
        & Me.last_name & "', '" 
        & Me.full_name & "', '" 
        & Me.instructor_sis_id & "', '" 
        & Me.instructor_email & "', '" 
        & Me.intstructor_net_id & "', '" 
        & Me.personal_email & "', '" 
        & Me.CV_link & "', '" 
        & Me.employee_nyu_global_site & "', '" 
        & Me.highest_degree & "', '" 
        & Me.degree_subject_area & "', '" 
        & Me.degree_status & "', '" 
        & Me.degree_granting_institution & "', '" 
        & Me.accomplishments & "', , '" 
        & Me.Other_employee & "', '" 
        & Me.WSQ_home_campus & "', '" 
        & Me.teaching_language_course & "')"
```

[image: Error text]

Comment: Now that your question is formatted correctly you should go back and add more than a picture of your less than informed error dialog. You need to add error logs or more details about what the error is and what you did other than post a feeble attempt at a question.

Comment: I would recommend saving the insert statement to a string first and piping out the string to a message box window and then trouble shooting though Query window.  I'm going to guess you have a missing ', a data type conversion issue, or a missing value for a field or vice versa.  but to format the SQL above is a bit of a pain.  Yep 21 fields, 22 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two commas in your value between accomplishments and employee field.

```
'" & Me.accomplishments & "', , '" & Me.Other_employee & "'
```

Delete any one of them will make it work.

Comment: Assuming that they didn't forget a field instead of an extra values and that the data types beyond it are corresponding to the data types in the values, or that an implicit convert will occur...  I agree this is where the problem is, but I don't know if simply removing the comma will solve the problem. (good start as any though)

Comment: Thank You Chong. It was really tedious to find an error for me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: In that case, I think leaving blank in column names part will work. Anyway, best in practice is to construct values in a loop one by one.